# gazebo-2.0 is called when I want to execute gazebo-5.0.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Given that I had two version of gazebo now ,2.0 and 5.0.

When I want to execute gazebo-5.0.0 (typing :  ./usr/local/gazebo5/bin/gazebo-5.0.0)
,it turned out that gazebo-2.0 is called

But if I execute gzserver and gzclient separately, correct version ( aka gzserver-5.0 and gzclient 5.0)are called.

"which" command output
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gnjq42j3p18ibk/rjIevpxFHLAxL-xlucwk_0z6laQFKI3zUz4ddXuA0og.png?dl=0

I have checked the shared library linked to gazebo-5.0.0,and their version are correct.

How can I deal with this problem? Thank you!

ldd gazebo-5.0.0 | grep gazebo

```
libgazebo_common.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_common.so.5 (0x00007f194247c000)
libgazebo_util.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_util.so.5 (0x00007f194221f000)
libgazebo_transport.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_transport.so.5 (0x00007f1941fb1000)
libgazebo_physics.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_physics.so.5 (0x00007f1941c2e000)
libgazebo_sensors.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_sensors.so.5 (0x00007f1941978000)
libgazebo_msgs.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_msgs.so.5 (0x00007f19415d0000)
libgazebo_math.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_math.so.5 (0x00007f1940798000)
libgazebo_physics_ode.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_physics_ode.so.5 (0x00007f193e022000)
libgazebo_rendering.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_rendering.so.5 (0x00007f193d985000)
libgazebo_ode.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_ode.so.5 (0x00007f193a468000)
libgazebo_skyx.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_skyx.so.5 (0x00007f1939b03000)
libgazebo_selection_buffer.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_selection_buffer.so.5 (0x00007f19398f4000)
libgazebo_rendering_deferred.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_rendering_deferred.so.5 (0x00007f1938893000)
libgazebo_opcode.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_opcode.so.5 (0x00007f1935d24000)
libgazebo_opende_ou.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_opende_ou.so.5 (0x00007f1935b1f000)
libgazebo_ccd.so.5 => /usr/local/gazebo5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_ccd.so.5 (0x00007f1935914000)
```

hello, here is my output

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rcterv2jz05iln/02.png?dl=0

Thank you,
this line does work!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhwaolnmevew0n1/01.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wryeosvfpek1osh/03.png?dl=0

but, I don't understand when I simply change into /usr/local/gazebo/bin and entering "./gazebo", I can't make a success?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8791/gazebo-2.0-is-called-when-i-want-to-execute-gazebo-5.0.0/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2015-05-23**:
Could you please edit the question and include the output of: `which gazebo`, `which gzserver`, `which gzclient`. ldd output is not really useful in this case.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2015-06-02**:
Looks like you have many installation of gazebo present in your system. I'm assuming that you have gazebo2 installed from packages, into /usr, and gazebo5 into /usr/local/gazebo5. Why do you have gazebo executables into /usr/local/bin? Could you please attach also: `find /usr -name 'gz*' -o -name 'gazebo'`. Also, what happen if you run: PATH="/usr/local/gazebo5/bin:${PATH}" gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When installing gazebo in non default paths (looks like yours is /usr/local/gazebo5) it is necessary to source the correct setup.sh, so environment variables are modified according to work with non default paths.

Did you run:

```
source /usr/local/gazebo5/share/setup.sh
```

before running gazebo?

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2015-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-05-26**:
Thank you~ ,I did ,but doesn't work  :(

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2015-05-26**:
Could you please edit the question and include the output of: `which gazebo`, `which gzserver`, `which gzclient`.